# SQL Json null value openjson

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

When I run this I get an error how do I take into consideration that the value could be null and it not throw a error ?

```
       declare @Concepts varchar(500)

    set @Concepts = '{"Concepts":null}';

   select [value] from openjson(@Concepts,'strict $.Concepts')
```

when it is not null

```
    set @Concepts = '{"Concepts": [4324,2342]}';
```

This is the error I am getting

***Value referenced by JSON path is not an array or object and cannot be opened with OPENJSON.***

Comment: What is the error you're getting? A null reference exception using the result of the query, or an error parsing/running the query? Please note that NULLs behave differently in SQL than most other languages (e.g. do not try `X = NULL` instead do `X IS NULL` and `X IS NOT NULL` instead).

Comment: Value referenced by JSON path is not an array or object and cannot be opened with OPENJSON. is the error understand they behave differently I am more talking about where there is a null in my JSON

Comment: What's `Concepts` supposed to be when it's not `null`? The correct answer depends on whether it's another JSON object or a scalar value.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I figured out taking the string `'strict'` out of `'strict $.Concepts'` solved my issue

```
 declare @Concepts varchar(500)
 set @Concepts = '{"Concepts":null}';
 select [value] from openjson(@Concepts,'$.Concepts')
```

Comment: Jeez. Now I feel silly... I missed this because I tested with `{"Concepts":3}`. In that case this approach won't work because it will not return any rows. (Neither will my suggested answer, though, which will henceforth be deleted.) The one thing of note is that the omission of `strict` means this query will succeed even if the `Concepts` property is missing *entirely*, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: I appreciate your help in my scenario I don't care if it is missing entirely I am new to JSON and SQL server so any help I can get is appreciated.